# Is there an R package or function for tuning logistic regression hyperparameters?

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression, hyperparameters

Is there an R package or function for tuning logistic regression hyperparameters similar to what can be done in Python? As far as I know, the glm function has no hyperparameters available to tune, even though there are several different hyperparameters for logistic regression. Is this just something that is not possible to do in R as it is in Python? Does the glm function just set them at fixed, default values and not allow the user to try different values? Is there a way to alter the original code of the glm function to specify different hyperparameters?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there are no tunable hyperparameters in `glm`, but there are other logistic regression functions where hyperparameters are tunable.

The [tidymodels](https://www.tidymodels.org/start/) package is very convenient for machine learning using R. It streamlines hyperparameter tuning for various data preprocessing (e.g. PCA, ...) and modelling approaches (`glm` and many others).

You can tune the hyperparameters of a **logistic regression** using e.g. the `glmnet` method (engine), where `penalty` (lambda) and `mixture` (alpha) can be tuned.

**Specify logistic regression model using `tidymodels`**

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(glmnet)

# show tunable hyperparameters for various logistic regression functions
show_model_info("logistic_reg")
#> Information for `logistic_reg`
#>  modes: unknown, classification 
#> 
#>  engines: 
#>    classification: glm, glmnet, keras, LiblineaR, spark, stan
#> 
#>  arguments: 
#>    glmnet:    
#>       penalty --> lambda
#>       mixture --> alpha
#>    LiblineaR: 
#>       penalty --> cost
#>       mixture --> type
#>    spark:     
#>       penalty --> reg_param
#>       mixture --> elastic_net_param
#>    keras:     
#>       penalty --> penalty
#> 
#>   [fit and prediction modules omitted to be more concise]

mod <- logistic_reg(mode = "classification", engine = "glmnet",
                    penalty = tune(), mixture = tune())
```

**tune hyperparameters using `tidymodels`**

```r
## specify recipe: model formula and preprocessing steps (if any)
rec <- recipe(Group ~ Class1 + Class2, data = data)

## specify workflow (recipe and model specification)
w <- workflow(preprocessor = rec, spec = mod)

## specify resamples for cross-validation
set.seed(28483)
r <- vfold_cv(data = data, v = 10, repeats = 1, strata = "Group")

## specify tuning grid (hyperparameter search space)
g <- expand_grid(penalty = c(0,1,2),
                 mixture = seq(0,1,by=0.2))

## tune logistic regression model
fit_tune <- tune_grid(w, resamples = r, grid = g)
```

**collect and plot tuning results**

```r
tune.met <- collect_metrics(fit_tune)
tune.met
#> # A tibble: 36 × 8
#>    penalty mixture .metric  .estimator  mean     n std_err .config              
#>      <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>                
#>  1       0     0   accuracy binary     0.785    10  0.0299 Preprocessor1_Model01
#>  2       0     0   roc_auc  binary     0.877    10  0.0244 Preprocessor1_Model01
#>  3       1     0   accuracy binary     0.785    10  0.0299 Preprocessor1_Model02
#>  4       1     0   roc_auc  binary     0.875    10  0.0251 Preprocessor1_Model02
#>  5       2     0   accuracy binary     0.785    10  0.0299 Preprocessor1_Model03
#>  6       2     0   roc_auc  binary     0.875    10  0.0251 Preprocessor1_Model03
#>  7       0     0.2 accuracy binary     0.785    10  0.0299 Preprocessor1_Model04
#>  8       0     0.2 roc_auc  binary     0.876    10  0.0245 Preprocessor1_Model04
#>  9       1     0.2 accuracy binary     0.775    10  0.0271 Preprocessor1_Model05
#> 10       1     0.2 roc_auc  binary     0.847    10  0.0265 Preprocessor1_Model05
#> # … with 26 more rows

ggplot(tune.met, aes(x = mixture, y = mean, colour = factor(penalty))) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~.metric) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
# show best
fit_tune %>% show_best(metric = "accuracy")
#> # A tibble: 5 × 8
#>   penalty mixture .metric  .estimator  mean     n std_err .config              
#>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>                
#> 1       0     0   accuracy binary     0.785    10  0.0299 Preprocessor1_Model01
#> 2       1     0   accuracy binary     0.785    10  0.0299 Preprocessor1_Model02
#> 3       2     0   accuracy binary     0.785    10  0.0299 Preprocessor1_Model03
#> 4       0     0.2 accuracy binary     0.785    10  0.0299 Preprocessor1_Model04
#> 5       0     0.4 accuracy binary     0.785    10  0.0299 Preprocessor1_Model07
```

**toy data used**

```r
library(tidyverse)
#set.seed(1)
x1 = rnorm(100, mean = 45, sd = 5); x2 = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 3); 
z1 = rnorm(100, mean = 13, sd = 1.3); z2 = rnorm(100, mean = 15, sd = 2.3)
Y0 = rep("No", 100);Y1 = rep("Yes",100)
a = c(x2,x1); b = c(z2,z1); c = c(Y0,Y1); 
data = tibble(Group = factor(c), Class1 = a, Class2 = b)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>